# Oozie - How to postpone a workflow until another one completes

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have a bundle that runs several coordinators.
While one (and specific one) of these coordinators runs (a daily time-scheduled workflow), no other one has to start. Is there a way to postpone or cancel all other coordinators until this one completes ?

**Example:**

- C1: Runs once a day at 06:00. Has to run alone!
- C2: Runs every 15 minutes (and take about 5 mins to complete)
- C3: Runs once a day at 04:00 (and could take more than 2 hours to complete)

What I need is:

- C1 starts only if C2 & C3 are not running, else wait for its completion to start
- C2 starts only if C1 is not running, else cancel itself

If it's not possible, is there a workaround ?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible, and for several good reasons. One is that Oozie scheduling is **not** instantaneous => even if C1 triggers a Workflow at 06:00 which submits its first Action job at 06:01, it may not be launched by YARN before 06:10 (depending on workload)... and may not effectively start before 06:11. The last Action of C3 may have finished in between. Or have failed before and been retried (automatically or manually)...

Comment: So you could chain C1 as a sub-workflow of C3, after a dummy shell script that "sleeps" until 06:00.For C2 I see no reliable workaround, except launching a _SUSPEND_ command from inside C3 (yuck!), but then how to manage the race condition...  (yuck again!)

Comment: So IMHO you have two choices: buy an Enterprise Scheduler like CONTROL-M; or change your mindset and find a way to make C2 non-exclusive with the other two. E.g. C3 captures the current "state" on startup and does not process newer data, then passes that "state" to C1.